# @font-face not recognized in Visual Studio

Tags: css, visual-studio, fonts, font-face

I'm in Visual Studio and it's not recognizing the keyword "font" in the expression "@font-face". It's a mature HTML MVC app with all kinds of functionality, but when I tried to add the following code to load a custom font, it's not recognized.

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
   font-family:comic;
   src:url(test.eot);
}
</style>
```

Tooltip error message:

> The name 'font' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Yes, I have faced it earlier. Are you trying to add it in cshtml ? or in css ?

Comment: I'm adding it to the .cshtml file.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"Razor examines the content on the right-hand side of any @ character and attempts to determine whether it is C# code (if it is a CSHTML file).

In cases where the content is valid as code as well (and you want to treat it as content), you can explicitly escape out @ characters by typing @@."

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-razor

Add @@ instead of @ in .cshtml file for font-face.

Comment: That was it! I'm surprised I've never encountered the need for double @ before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1.Create a CSS file for example "Fonts.css"

2.Drag your fonts you need to include to your project to "Fonts.css"

3.Include the "Fonts.css" in your View

َAnd try to add fonts

This is one of the ways that I think can help you